# tree and blocks

Tags: diagrams, trees

stackexchange members, I tried to do this but unfortunately I couldn't. It is really simple. I found some codes and tried to get similar picture as mine.

[image]

and second image is

[image]

Thank you so for your help and I am so sorry for taking your time. with regards.

Comment: Welcome! Can you post what you tried? Even a beginning would help get things started.

Comment: @cfr I just seen your question and answer at the same time. should I post still what I tried to do. and I was trying to do intervals as well.. anyway, I edited and added my humble trying :(.

Comment: I tried to  add my humble trying :(. then I deleted it again. because it is so simple.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One option using the powerful [`forest`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/forest) package:

[image]

The code (with explanatory comments):

```
\documentclass[varwidth=30cm,border=4pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

% The width of the [0,1] Intervals
\newlength\IntervalWd
\setlength\IntervalWd{5cm}

% Style for the upper labels in the intervals
\tikzset{
  numlabel/.style={above,pos=#1,font=\scriptsize,text=magenta}
}

% Command to draw the intervals
% Syntax
% \DrawInterval[base]{divisions}{lables}{position}
\newcommand\DrawInterval[4][2]{
  \draw[|-|] 
    (#4) node[below=3pt] {$0$} --
    ++(\IntervalWd,0pt) node[below=3pt] {$1$};
 \ifnum#2=1\relax
   \node[above,text=magenta,font=\scriptsize] at ([xshift=0.5\IntervalWd]#4) {1};
 \else   
  \foreach \Valor in {1,...,#2}
  {
    \draw 
      ([xshift=\Valor*(1/#2)*\IntervalWd] $ (#4) + (0,-2pt) $ ) --
      ++(0,4pt);
    \node[xshift=\Valor*(1/#2)*\IntervalWd,above,text=magenta,font=\scriptsize]
      at ([xshift=-0.5\Valor*(1/#2)*\IntervalWd]#4) 
      {\pgfmathprint{int(mod(\Valor-1,#1))}};
  }
  \foreach \Texto [count=\xi] in {#3}
  {
    \node[xshift=\xi*(1/#2)*\IntervalWd,anchor=base,yshift=-10pt,font=\scriptsize]
      at (#4) 
      {$\Texto$};
  }
  \fi  
}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
for tree={
  circle,
  fill,
  inner sep=1.5pt,
  parent anchor=south,
  s sep=20pt
},
delay={
  for tree={
    if n=1  
      {edge label={node[midway,left,text=magenta,font=\scriptsize] {$0$}}}
      {if n'=1  
        {edge label={node[midway,right,text=magenta,font=\scriptsize] {$1$}}}
        {}
      }
  },
}
[$\emptyset$,fill=none,name=level0
  [
    [ [,name=level3l] [] ]
    [ [] [] ]
  ]
  [,name=level1
    [ [] [] ]
    [,name=level2 [] [,name=level3] ]
  ]
]
% Auxiliary coordinates
\coordinate (aux1) at ([xshift=20pt]level3|-level0);
\coordinate (aux2) at ([xshift=2cm]level3|-level0);
\coordinate (aux3) at ([xshift=2cm+20pt]level3|-level0);
\coordinate (aux4) at ([xshift=-20pt]level3l|-level0);
% The level number
\foreach \Valor in {0,...,3}
{
  \node at  (aux4|-level\Valor) {\Valor};
}
% The arrows
\foreach \Valor in {0,...,3}
{
  \draw[<->,>=latex]
    (aux1|-level\Valor) -- (aux2|-level\Valor);
}
% The [0,1] intervals
%level0
\DrawInterval{1}{}{aux3|-level0}
%level1
\DrawInterval{2}{1/2}{aux3|-level1}
%level2
\DrawInterval{4}{1/4,1/2,3/4}{aux3|-level2}
%level2
\DrawInterval{8}{1/8,1/4,3/8,1/2,5/8,3/4,7/8}{aux3|-level3}
\end{forest}\par\bigskip

\begin{forest}
for tree={
  circle,
  fill,
  inner sep=1.5pt,
  parent anchor=south,
  s sep=15pt,
  l sep=30pt,
  if level=1{s sep=27pt}{}
},
delay={
  for tree={
    if n=1  
      {edge label={node[midway,left,text=magenta,font=\scriptsize] {$0$}}}
      {if n'=1  
        {edge label={node[midway,right,text=magenta,font=\scriptsize] {$2$}}}
        {edge label={node[midway,left,text=magenta,font=\scriptsize] {$1$}}}
      }
  },
}
[$\emptyset$,fill=none,name=level0
  [,edge={magenta}
    [,name=level2] [] [,edge={magenta}]
  ]
  [
    [] [] []
  ]
  [
    [] [] []
  ]
]
% Auxiliary coordinates
\coordinate (aux1) at ([xshift=-20pt] $ (level2|-level0)!0.5!(level2) $ );
\coordinate (aux2) at ([xshift=-2cm]aux1);
\coordinate (aux3) at ([xshift=-20pt]aux2);
\coordinate (aux4) at ([xshift=-\IntervalWd]aux3);
\draw[<->,>=latex]
  (aux1) -- (aux2);
\DrawInterval[3]{9}{,,1/3,,,2/3,,}{aux4}
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I guess I can take care of the rest. I am so grateful.

Comment: @Airbag You are welcome. In some minutes I'll update with an improved code for the intervals.

Comment: @Airbag Answer updated.

Answer (score 2):

This version uses the experimental `prooftrees` package, which has been slightly updated to make it possible.

The code requires version 0.08 of `prooftrees` or later (included below). This requires `forest` as the package is built on top of `forest`. It is primarily designed for typesetting logical tree proofs easily. One of the key issues there is to align line numbers on the left and justifications on the right. Here, the spaces on the right are used to draw the number lines, and the line numbering is adjusted using a couple of things added to `prooftrees` so that it would be easy to match the style shown in the question.

## First diagram

[image: aligned tree]

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{prooftrees}% v 0.08
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, positioning}
\begin{document}
  \renewcommand\linenumberstyle[1]{#1}% default uses dots after the number
  \forestset{
    my label/.style n args=2{
      edge label={node [midway, text=red, font=\scriptsize, #1] {$#2$}}
    },
  }
  \begin{prooftree}{
      zero start,% default starts numbering with 1
      line justifications,% justifications must be explicitly enabled as their content is not specified directly
      just format/.style={% this is used to draw the arrows and number lines on the right (where the justifications for inferences would go in a tree proof in logic)
        before drawing tree={
          tikz/.wrap 2 pgfmath args={
            [font=\scriptsize]
            \draw [{Stealth[]}-{Stealth[]}] (!<.base east) +(1.5mm,0) -- (.base) -- ++(10mm,0) coordinate (c);
            \draw [font=\small]
               [{Bar[width=10pt]}-{Bar[width=10pt]}] (c) ++(5pt,0) node (n1) [below=5pt] {$0$} -- ++(50mm,0) node (n2) [below=5pt] {$1$};
            \ifnum##2>1
            \path (n1 |- c) -- (n2 |- c) node [pos=.5/##2, above, text=red] {0} foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \ieval using {int(mod(\i,2))}] in {1,...,##1} { node [pos={(\i+.5)/##2}, above, text=red] {\ieval} node (nn\i) [pos=\i/##2, below=2.5pt] {$\frac{\i}{##2}$}};
              \foreach \i in {1,...,##1} \draw (c -| nn\i) +(0,2.5pt) -- +(0,-2.5pt);
            \fi
          }{int((2^(level()-1))-1)}{int(2^(level()-1))},
        }
      },
      for tree={% this sets up the main tree, rooted at the empty set symbol
        math content,
        if level=1{}{
          circle,
          fill,
          minimum size=2.5pt,
          inner sep=0pt,
          outer sep=0pt,
          if n=1{% add the red labels on the sides automatically
            if level=2{
              my label={above left}{0}
            }{
              my label={left}{0}
            },
          }{
            if n'=1{
              if level=2{
                my label={above right}{1}
              }{
                my label={right}{1}
              },
            }{}
          }
        },
        if level=0{% increase the separation a bit - necessary to stop squishing with the additional level added here for demonstration purposes
          for descendants={s sep+=5pt},
        }{},
      }
    },
    [\emptyset% this is the root of the main tree
      [[[[][]][[][]]][[[][]][[][]]]]% main left branch
      [[[[][]][[][]]][[[][]][[][]]]]% main right branch
    ]
  \end{prooftree}
\end{document}
```

Note that there is an additional, invisible level above the first visible level. This is all created automatically. You only need to know this if you want to do things with the level information. In the code below, for example, I use this information to create the number lines. So it matters that the empty set symbol is at level 1 as far as `forest` is concerned even though it is at level 0 as far as the diagram is concerned.

## Package

Save the following as `prooftrees.sty` and stick it in the same directory as your `.tex` file:

```
%% Copyright 2015 cfr
%%
\ProvidesPackage{prooftrees}[2015/07/20 v0.08 prooftrees]
\RequirePackage{forest}                                                                                                                    
\newcounter{prooftree@countlevels}% count the levels in the proof tree                                                                     
\setcounter{prooftree@countlevels}{0}                                                                                                      
\newcount\prooftree@lcount% count the line numbers (on the left)                                                                           
\newcount\prooftree@jcount% count the justifications (on the right)                                                                        
\newcount\prooftree@linenoshift% adjustment for line numbering
\newcommand*\linenumberstyle[1]{#1.}
\forestset{
  declare boolean={numbers}{0},% line numbering
  declare boolean={justifiers}{0},% line justifications
  declare boolean={verticals}{0},% single branches
  grouped/.style={% this adjusts the alignment of line numbers and justifications when some levels of the tree are grouped together either whenever the number of children is only 1 or by applying the grouped style to particular nodes when specifying the tree
        before computing xy={
          l=\baselineskip,
          if={\forestove{numbers}==1}{
                if={\forestove{justifiers}==1}{
                  node walk={
                        every step/.style={l=\baselineskip},
                        after walk/.style={l=\baselineskip},
                        name/.wrap pgfmath arg={just ##1}{level()},
                        name/.wrap pgfmath arg={line no ##1}{level()},
                  },
                }{
                  node walk={
                        after walk/.style={l=\baselineskip},
                        name/.wrap pgfmath arg={line no ##1}{level()},
                  },
                },
          }{
                if={\forestove{justifiers}==1}{
                  node walk={
                        after walk/.style={l=\baselineskip},
                        name/.wrap pgfmath arg={just ##1}{level()}
                  },
                }{},
          },
        },
        no edge,
  },
  close/.style={
        label={[yshift=2.5pt]below:$\otimes$},
  },
  line no/.style={% creates the line numbers on the left
        no edge,
        before typesetting nodes={% page 51
          TeX={\advance\prooftree@lcount1},
          content/.expanded/.wrap pgfmath arg={\linenumberstyle{##1}}{int(\linecounter+\the\prooftree@linenoshift)},% content i.e. the line number
          name/.expanded={line no \the\prooftree@lcount},% name them so they can be moved later
          if={\the\prooftree@lcount>2}{% the initial location of most line numbers is incorrect and they must be moved
                for previous={% move the line number below the previous line number
                  append/.expanded={line no \the\prooftree@lcount}
                },
          }{},
        },
  },
  line justification/.style={% creates the justifications on the right but does not yet specify any content
        anchor=base west,
        no edge,
        before typesetting nodes={% page 51
          TeX={\advance\prooftree@jcount1},
          name/.expanded={just \the\prooftree@jcount},% name them so they can be moved
          if={\the\prooftree@jcount>2}{% correct the location as for the line numbers (cf. line no style)
                for previous={
                  append/.expanded={just \the\prooftree@jcount}
                },
          }{},
        },
  },
  line numbering/.style={
        for tree={numbers},
  },
  no line numbering/.style={
        for tree={not numbers},
  },
  line numbering shift/.style={
        TeX={\advance\prooftree@linenoshift#1},
  },
  zero start/.style={
        line numbering shift=-1,
  },
  line justifications/.style={
        for tree={justifiers},
  },
  no line justifications/.style={
        for tree={not justifiers},
  },
  single branches/.style={
        for tree={verticals},
  },
  no single branches/.style={
        for tree={not verticals},
  },
  to prove/.style={
        before typesetting nodes={
          if level=0{
                content={#1},
                phantom=false,
          }{}
        }
  },
  proof tree/.style={
        for tree={
          parent anchor=south,
          line numbering,
          delay={
                where content={}{
                  shape=coordinate,
                }{}
          },
        },
        where level=0{
          for children={
                no edge,
          },
          delay={
                if content={}{phantom}{},
                if={(\forestove{numbers}==1) || (\forestove{justifiers}==1)}{% count the levels if necessary
                  for descendants={
                        if={level()>\value{prooftree@countlevels}}{
                          TeX={
                                \stepcounter{prooftree@countlevels}
                          },
                        }{},
                  },
                }{},
                if={(\forestove{numbers}==1)}{% create the line numbers if appropriate
                  prepend={
                        [,
                          line no,
                          line no format,
                          repeat={\value{prooftree@countlevels}-1}{% most are created in the wrong place but line no moves them later
                                delay n={\the\prooftree@lcount}{
                                        append={[, line no, line no format]}
                                },
                          }
                        ]
                  },
                }{},
                if={(\forestove{justifiers}==1}{% create the nodes which will hold the justifications, if required
                  append={
                        [,
                          fit=rectangle,
                          just format,
                          line justification,
                          repeat={\value{prooftree@countlevels}-1}{% most are created in the wrong place but line justification moves them later
                                delay n={\the\prooftree@jcount}{
                                  append={[, line justification, just format]}
                                },
                          }
                        ]
                  }
                }{},
          },
        }{
          delay={
                if={(\forestove{verticals}==0}{% automatically group lines if not using single branches
                  if n children=1{
                        for children={
                          if ={(\forestove{verticals}==0}{
                                grouped
                          }{},
                        }
                  }{},
                }{},
          }
        },
        before packing={
          for tree={
                tier/.wrap pgfmath arg={tier ##1}{level()},
          },
        },
  },
  just/.style={
        if={\forestove{justifiers}==0}{
          for root={
                line justifications,
          },
        }{},
          before packing={% puts the content of the justifications into the empty justification nodes on the right; because this is done late, the nodes need to be typeset again
                for={name/.wrap pgfmath arg={just ##1}{level()}}{
                  content={#1},
                  typeset node
                },
          }
  },
  toing/.style={% this is here so I can easily override no edge when to line={} is used
        edge path={
          \noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) -- (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
        },
  },
  to line/.style={% this option is intended for use with justifications and, although it should not give an error, it will have no effect in other cases (There is simply no reason to typeset a proof with this if not giving justifications, that I can think of)
        if={#1>\value{prooftree@countlevels}}{% ensure that we get enough lines in the tree since #1 may well specify a line which would not otherwise exist
          TeX={
                \setcounter{prooftree@countlevels}{#1}
          },
        }{},
        if={#1>level()}{% only try to move the node if the target line number exceeds the current level
          if={\forestove{justifiers}==0}{% don't do anything if there are no justifications - there is no point in moving things in such a case
          }{
                if={\forestove{verticals}==0}{% if no single branches, get the vertical alignment from the correctly aligned line justification
                  before drawing tree={
                        y/.wrap pgfmath arg={##1}{y("!name={just #1}")},
                        toing
                  },
                }{
                  before packing={% if single branches, a simple tier alignment suffices
                        tier=tier #1,
                  },
                },
          },
        }{},
  },
  just to line/.style n args=2{
        if={\forestove{justifiers}==0}{
          for root={
                line justifications,
          },
        }{},
        if={#1>\value{prooftree@countlevels}}{% make sure the tree contains enough lines since #1 may exceed the total line count otherwise
          TeX={
                \setcounter{prooftree@countlevels}{#1}
          },
        }{},
        if={#1>level()}{% only if the target line number exceeds the current level
          before packing={
                for={name={just #1}}{% specify the content of the target line justification and, because this is done late, typeset the node again
                  content={#2},
                  typeset node
                },
          }
        }{% do nothing if the target line number is less than the current level
          if={#1==level()}{% only if the target line number equals the current level
                just=#2,
          }{},
        },
  },
  just format/.style={},
  line no format/.style={},
}
\newcommand*\linecounter{\linecountformat{\the\prooftree@lcount}}
\newcommand*\linecountformat[1]{#1.}
\environbodyname\prooftreebody
\bracketset{action character=@}
\NewEnviron{prooftree}[1]{% \forest/\endforest from egreg's answer at http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/229608/
  \forest
        proof tree,
        #1,
        [@\prooftreebody]
  \endforest}
\endinput
%% end prooftrees.sty
```

Comment: Note that the variation in line thicknesses is an artefact of my viewer/screen and not 'real' (whatever that means).

Comment: thanks a lot cfr for your time and effort. Long \leftrightarrow  are better but i feel like writing 3/4,1/2,1/4 is good for understanding. it is not a big deal, though. But here I think i can't change it.

Comment: @Airbag You don't have to use all the automatisation I put in ;). Not sure I understand about 'Long `\leftrightarrow`' as I didn't use anything like that.... Is there a particular reason to put the number line on the left in the second diagram? Just curious....