# qtree - labeling levels of a tree

Tags: tikz-qtree, qtree

In either `tikz-qtree` or `qtree`, is it possible to label or number different levels of a (vertical) tree? Such labels could be at the right or the left side of the whole tree.

Comment: Don't know about `tikz-qtree` but I've done this with `qtree`. However, it is not at all straightforward. I would not do it this way now I've got better options. I would either use or modify an experimental solution I have based on `forest`. (Use if the tree is proof-like in structure, or modify otherwise.) But maybe this isn't an option for you. An MWE would obviously help.

Comment: Warning: I've written a bunch of answers involving different versions of `prooftrees.sty` and `justtrees.sty`. A recent-ish example is http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/256184/tree-and-blocks/256245#256245. But ask if you plan to use any of this and I'll give you a current version of the package. `prooftrees` is at version 0.08 and `justtrees` at version 0.04. If you search for `prooftrees` and look for answers by me, you can find some examples.

Comment: Wow — that's beautiful. But I suspect it's more than I need. I'll keep things simple for now.

Comment: @brannerchinese For a simple `tikz-qtree` solution see [How can I align captions with each level of a tree drawn with tikz-qtree?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55003/2693)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `\node`s to name some special nodes and allow getting access to their position in the tree and then use the named nodes to place the text. A little example placing text at both sides:

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\Tree 
[.\node (level0-right) {S}; 
  [.NP 
    [.Det \node (level3-left) {the}; 
    ] 
    [.N cat 
    ] 
  ]
  [.\node (level1-right) {VP}; 
    [.V sat 
    ]
    [.\node (level2-right) {PP}; 
      [.P on 
      ]
      [.\node (level3-right) {NP}; 
        [.Det the 
        ] 
        [.\node (level4-right) {N}; \node (level5-right) {mat}; 
        ] 
      ]
    ] 
  ] 
]
\foreach \Value/\Text in {0/{Texto 1},1/{Texto 2},2/{Texto 3},3/{Texto 4},4/{Texto 5},5/{Texto 6}}
{  
  \node[anchor=west] 
    at ([xshift=1cm]{level5-right}|-{level\Value-right}) 
    {\Text};
  \node[anchor=east] 
    at ([xshift=-1cm]{level3-left}|-{level\Value-right}) 
    {\Text};
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) But too much typing;.

Answer (score 2):

Just for the heck of it, here's [Gonzalo Medina's example tree](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/268464/) with `prooftrees`:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{prooftrees}% version 0.8
\begin{document}
\begin{prooftree}
  {
    single branches
  }
  [S, just=explan 1
    [NP, just=explan 2
      [Det [the]]
      [N [cat]]
    ]
    [VP
      [V [sat]]
      [PP, just=explan 3
        [P [on]]
        [NP, just=explan 4
          [Det, just=explan 5 [the, just=explan 6]]
          [N [mat]]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{prooftree}
\end{document}
```

[image: proof cats on mats]

Note that the numbering on the left is automatic. (It can be switched off, but it is default.) Bear in mind, though, that the package is really designed specifically for logical proofs and not for other kinds of trees.

## EDIT

Here's the same tree with some overlay specifications in Beamer:

[image: overlay specifications with tree]

This is using the standard definitions I use for `tikzpicture`s generally and `forest` trees, in particular:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{prooftrees}% version 0.8
\tikzset{% set up for transitions using tikz with beamer overlays
    invisible/.style={opacity=0,text opacity=0},
    visible on/.style={alt=#1{}{invisible}},
    alt/.code args={<#1>#2#3}{%
      \alt<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}} % \pgfkeysalso doesn't change the path
    },
    transparent/.style={opacity=0.1,text opacity=0.1},
    opaque on/.style={alt=#1{}{transparent}},
    alerted/.style={color=red},
    alert on/.style={alt=#1{alerted}{}},
}
\forestset{%
  visible on/.style={%
        for tree={%
          /tikz/visible on={#1},
          edge={/tikz/visible on={#1}}}},
  opaque on/.style={%
        for tree={%
          /tikz/opaque on={#1},
          edge={/tikz/opaque on={#1}}}},
  alerted on/.style={%
        for tree={%
          /tikz/alerted on={#1},
          edge={/tikz/alerted on={#1}}}},
}%
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{A Tree}
\begin{prooftree}
  {
    single branches,
  }
  [S, just=explan 1
    [NP, just=explan 2, alert on=<4->, for children={opaque on=<5->}
      [Det [the]]
      [N [cat]]
    ]
    [VP
      [V [sat]]
      [PP, just=explan 3
        [P [on]]
        [NP, just=explan 4, alert on=<2>
          [Det, just=explan 5, opaque on=<3-> [the, just=explan 6]]
          [N [mat]]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{prooftree}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: A lot of the interesting functionality of `tikz-qtree` doesn't work with `beamer` — "growing" trees upward, for instance. How does `prooftree` react to being in the same soup with `beamer`?

Comment: @brannerchinese Testing suggests it works similar to `forest`, which is quite well. You just need a few TikZ and `forest` styles and then you can use them within the tree. See edit for an example which uses transparency/opacity and alerted/regular transitions in the current example.

Comment: @brannerchinese What makes you say that `tikz-qtree` doesn't work well with `beamer`? See the answer to http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/268578/3954 for an example of uncovering a tree upwards using `tikz-qtree`.

Comment: Hm. Yes. It works now.