# beamer - uncovering parts of qtree syntax tree

Tags: beamer, qtree

I am using `qtree` to draw syntax trees in `beamer` (in the presence of `xeCJK` for Chinese language support, though I don't think that affects this question). I am able to reveal different levels of the tree progressively, using `\uncover` (see MWE below). But I'd like, in addition, to be able to uncover edges (lines) within the tree the same way. (Sorry — the StackExchange interface wouldn't allow me to post the question with CJK characters in place, so I substituted `X` for each.)

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass[compress]{beamer}

\usepackage{qtree}      % allows syntax trees
\usepackage{textcomp}   % allows \textrightarrow
\usepackage[AutoFallBack=true]{xeCJK}

\begin{document}

\frame{
  \Tree [.{\uncover<3->{(V)-V}}
    [.{\uncover<2->{(V)-V}} [.V X\\ten ] [.N\textrightarrow V X\\day ] ]
    [.{\uncover<2->{(V)-V}} [.V X\\one ] [.V X\\{to rain} ] ]
    ]

\uncover<4->{\vskip12pt To rain once in ten days.}

}

\end{document}
```

[image: Slide 1]

[image: Slide 2]

[image: Slide 3]

(final slide omitted)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest you switching the [`tikz-qtree`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-qtree) so you can use TikZ's features:

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz-qtree}      % allows syntax trees
\usepackage{textcomp}   % allows \textrightarrow
\usepackage[AutoFallBack=true]{xeCJK}

\tikzset{
  invisible/.style={opacity=0},
  visible on/.style={alt={#1{}{invisible}}},
  alt/.code args={<#1>#2#3}{%
    \alt<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}}
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \Tree 
   [. \node[visible on=<3->] {(V)-V};\edge [visible on=<3->];
    [. \node[visible on=<2->] {(V)-V};\edge [visible on=<2->]; 
      [.V \node[align=center] {X\\ ten}; ] 
      \edge [visible on=<2->]; [.N\textrightarrow V \node[align=center] {X\\ day}; ] 
    ]
    \edge [visible on=<3->]; [.\node[visible on=<2->] {(V)-V};\edge [visible on=<2->]; 
      [.V \node[align=center] {X\\ one}; ] 
      \edge [visible on=<2->]; [.V \node[align=center] {X \\ to rain}; ] 
    ]
  ];
\end{tikzpicture}
\uncover<4->{\vskip12pt To rain once in ten days.}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm assuming this works. And, even if it doesn't, it gets a (+1) for not being the code I used to persuade `qtree` to do this. But your image is not entirely successful in conveying the efficacy of your code. (Or is it an animation? They hardly ever work on this site for me.)

Comment: @cfr It's an animation. Why do you say it wouldn't work?

Comment: Just induction: animations occasionally work on the site for me, but mostly just look like images. Except when images don't work either, of course, then I just see the alternate text description. Mostly, images work and animations don't. It isn't a claim about your animation in particular ;).

Comment: Able to view as image. Splendid. I had initially tried using `tikz-qtree` in order to get the `[grow'=up]` effect (since in the Chinese language, trees have their roots at the bottom and their leaves at the top), but although my MWEs looked good, growing up didn't work once I was in `beamer`. Will try again. This is most impressive.

Answer (score 1):

*Can this be done?*

- Yes, at least within certain limits. For example, you can certainly uncover a tree in the direction of its growth, and some other possibilities are also available.

*Should I do this?*

- Probably not. There are easier ways, better packages and methods. I would never attempt to do this now. I would just use `forest`.

*Do I want to do this?*

- Probably not unless you have a distinctively masochistic streak. See previous answer.

*How can I do this?*

- See previous answers: you shouldn't be asking this question.

*Is doing this hazardous?*

- Definitely. It will make your mind feel as if it has been turned inside out - and not in a good way.

*Is it worth it?*

- Depends what floats your boat. Judge for yourself:

[image: incrementally uncover tree in Beamer]

*But, really, how do I do it?*

- This is how I did this... more-or-less. It was a bit more complicated than this, but this is the idea. Don't say I didn't warn you is all...

Code:

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}

\usepackage{qtree}      % allows syntax trees
\usepackage{textcomp}   % allows \textrightarrow
% uncover tableaux proofs incrementally by typesetting using the background colour for text and then resetting to normal
\mode<presentation>
{
  \newcommand<>{\cuddio}[1]{\color#2{bg}#1}
  \newcommand<>{\dangos}[1]{\color#2{fg}#1}
}
\mode<article>
{
  \def\cuddio<#1>#2{#2}
  \def\dangos<#1>#2{#2}
}

\begin{document}

\frame{
  \Tree [.{(V)-V} !{\cuddio<1>}
  [.{(V)-V} !{\cuddio<1>} [.V X\\ten ] [.N\textrightarrow V X\\day  ] !{\dangos<1>} ]
  [.{(V)-V} !{\cuddio<1-3>} [.V X\\one ] [.V X\\{to rain} ] !{\dangos<3>} ] !{\dangos<4>}
]

\uncover<4->{\vskip12pt To rain once in ten days.}

}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The use of background and foreground colors is very clever!

Comment: @brannerchinese More a sign of madness, I think. I can't believe I taught an entire semester of seminars using this method! And I had three trees for every proof which had to be kept in sync: numbers on the left, proof in the middle, justifications on the right.